# How to keep fresh lemon juice for a week without a change in its taste?

Tags: food-preservation, lemon, juice

Are there any way to preserve the juice of lemon for, say, one week without a change in its taste?

Even deep-freezing it makes it little bit bitter!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not think that there is a better way they **not to squeeze the lemon** until you need them **:D**

Regardless, if you want to do testing and are concerned about the bitter notes that develop , I recommend  doing the research with grapefruit instead as it turns bitter is a matter of minutes and has a much stronger bitter flavor then the lemons do. 
That way you at least have a shorter turn around time.

Answer (score 1):

No, not really. Pasteurization--cooking briefly at a high temperature to kill nasty bugs--changes the flavour of citrus fruits immeasurably. Just juice your lemons as needed.

Answer (score -1):

You need to freeze them and You can find all tips here http://drinklemonwater.com/ways-to-preserve-lemon-juice/